# Erlang - ** exception error: no match of right hand side value

Tags: json, erlang, pattern-matching

I have a problem with pattern match of json formatted string.
Here I add a shorted version (just changed long json string to "{\"jsondata\"}"
So i have this pattern match which is sucessfull:

```
 > MyData2={ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",200,"OK"},
         [{"connection","Keep-Alive"},
          {"date","Thu, 10 Sep 2015 12:03:49 GMT"},
          {"server","Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)"},
          {"vary","X-Auth-Token"},
          {"content-length","1171"},
          {"content-type","application/json"},
          {"x-openstack-request-id",
           "req-31b4efc1-2af4-4130-b7a8-01d94b456096"},
          {"keep-alive","timeout=5, max=100"}],
         "{\"jsondata\"}"}}.
```

After that I run the following:

```
> {ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",ReturnCode, State},B,J}}=MyData2.
```

unfortunatelly i get
If I change `"{\"jsondata\"}"` to `"jsondata"` the last pattern match works fine
I have no Idea how to extract the json and get in J the "{\"jsondata\"}"
I`ll appriciate any idea
    ** exception error: no match of right hand side value

Comment: It seems like you're getting this error because `MyData2` is already bound in the shell.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22281376/113848) for more information about that problem.

Comment: @legoscia - no it`s a new one and is not bound

Comment: Is it possible, that the variables `ReturnCode`, `State`, `B` or `J` are already bound? That would lead to a similiar problem, because they will be replaced by their bound values on the left hand side.

Comment: If I copy-paste everything and execute it in a new shell, the matching works perfectly. It has to be a variable-binding issue, like I just posted...

Comment: Same results as @maze-le: copy & paste everything in a new shell and it works fine. Also, just think about it: the only way to get an error message "no match of right hand side value" is for something on the left-hand side to already have a value that doesn't match the right-hand side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern matching operation works perfectly. I think the problem is, that one of the variables `ReturnCode`, `State`, `B` or `J` is already bound.

Lets assume the variable `J` is already bound to a value, and the other variables are not. Depending on this value, the pattern matching operation

```
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",ReturnCode, State},B,J}} = MyData2.
```

either succeeds or not.

**Case 1**:`J` is already bound to `"{\"jsondata\"}"`

Your pattern-match will succeed and the values of the unbound variables (`ReturnCode`, `State` and `B`) will be set, according to the pattern of `MyData2`.

**Case 2**:`J` is already bound to `"{jsondata}"`

The `J`-variable on the right hand side won't match the pattern of `MyData2` on the left hand side. Thus the execution fails with an exception.

This also happens on the shell if you forget to clear your variables with `f(Variable)`.